# replace spaces in string with comma

Tags: clojure

I need to take find all unique values from the below and pass them to a sql query.  Below is an example of what I am trying to do, I am actually taking the data from a two files comapring them and getting the unique values.

My problem is that I want to put the values in a sql `IN()` clause but I am having trouble comma separating the values

I have tried using replace but that does not seem to work for me

```
(def snapshot 
                #{{:id "1234" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"1235" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"10234" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"12034" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"127" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}}
)
 (def snapshot1 
                #{{:id"1238" :mtm "104" :pv"200"}
                {:id"234" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"124" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"123" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}
                {:id"134" :mtm "101" :pv"200"}}
)
(def SNAPSHOT-IDsT (set (map :id snapshot)))

(def SNAPSHOT-IDsT1 (set (map :id snapshot1)))

(def id-in-one-file-only (difference SNAPSHOT-IDsT1 SNAPSHOT-IDsT))

(println id-in-one-file-only)
```

this gives me `{1238 123 134 234 124}`

How can I edit these results to give me `{1238, 123, 134, 234, 124}`

So that I can then pass it to a string

```
(str "Select * from table where id in ("id-in-one-file-only")")
```

Any help or pointers with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`difference` returns a set, so I assume you have `#{1238 123 134 234 124}` as a result. How about a format fn:

```
user=> (defn format-ids [s]
         (str "{"
              (reduce #(str %1 ", " %2) s)
              "}"))

user=> (format-ids #{1238 123 134 234 124})
"{134, 234, 1238, 123, 124}"
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>`interpose` works nicely for this sort of thing:

`user=> (apply str (interpose \, #{1238 123 134 234 124}))
"134,234,1238,123,124"`</del>

Edit: amalloy is quite right, `clojure.string/join` is a much more efficient [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f30995c86056959abca53d0ca35dcb9cfa73e6e6/src/clj/clojure/string.clj#L130).

What I did above is what was in clojure.contrib v1.0 [str-join](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/1.0.0/src/clojure/contrib/str_utils.clj#L84)  (I suspect that my memory was playing tricks on me and that is where I saw interpose used in the first place).

Comment: `clojure.string/join` already does this. Don't hand-roll it with `apply str`/`interpose`.